# Why do some editors support Xelatex but some do not?

Tags: xetex, editors

I already know by experiments that Texstudio and Texworks do support Xelatex, namely they can "run" Xelatex. But I also know by experiments that there is some editor, say Bakoma, which does not support Xelatex.

According to my initial understanding, Xelatex is "runnable" because of Miktex (because I am using Miktex). How can editors matter?

Comment: As far as I know, BaKoMa TeX is not simply a front end/editor for TeX/LaTeX, but it runs `pdflatex` in the background to provide “live” typesetting. Since XeTeX works asynchronously, producing a PDF file after completing an XDV file (extended DVI format), I don't think it's possible to use it in BaKoMa TeX.

Comment: @egreg I am not sure of this, but, is it true that, apart from Bakoma's texword, any editor else supports Xelatex?

Comment: You need a button or a menu entry or a keyboard shortcut that calls xelatex. So the editor must either provide such a button, or allow some basic configuration to change/add menu entries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All front-end to TeX/LaTeX I know have no problem in supporting XeLaTeX for document compilation. Just set the preference on a global basis or for the specific document.

How to do it depends on the front-end or editor and it's not possible to give a thorough description for all of them. Check the documentation of the specific one you use.

BaKoMa TeX is a very different program: it only runs `pdftex` in the LaTeX variant (and recently also plain TeX or AMS-TeX). But it's a program that continuously runs the `pdftex` engine in order to provide “live typesetting”.

Unless its developer starts supporting XeTeX or LuaTeX, there's no possibility of running these engines with it.

Comment: Does it even use MikTeX? I thought it included its own TeX distribution. However, I have no idea why I thought this.

Comment: @cfr I think BaKoMa TeX uses its own TeX distribution.